# Image and text does not change in a single click on completion of Ajax call without an alert statement

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have made a script where I update a field value via AJAX and then I change the related text and image on the page without reload. There are multiple such links and the html for one of them is

```
<li>
    {% if object.attr1== 0 %}
        <IMG SRC="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/unchecked.jpeg">
    {% else %}
        <IMG SRC="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/check.jpeg">
    {% endif %}
    <span style="padding-left:5px"><a id="update" title="Click to update status" href="/update/{{object.id}}/1/">Attribute Name</a>:&nbsp; </span>
    <span id="sent_text">
        {% if object.attr1 == 0 %}
            Completed
        {% else %}
             Incomplete
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</li>
```

I basically send an AJAX link to the `href` of `a` tag. Since this is in `li` there are multiple such update links for different attributes of the object. My `javascript` is

```
$(function() {

    $("a#update").click(function(){

        var curr_elem = $(this) ;
        var link = $(this).attr("href");

        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: link,
              success: function() 
              { 
                var text = curr_elem.parent().parent().find('span#sent_text').text();
                if (text == 'Completed')
                {
                    curr_elem.parent().parent().find('span#sent_text').html('In complete');
                    curr_elem.parent().parent().find('IMG').attr("src", "/static/images/check.jpeg");
                }
                else
                {
                    curr_elem.parent().parent().find('span#sent_text').html('Completed');
                    curr_elem.parent().parent().find('IMG').attr("src", "/static/images/unchecked.jpeg");
                }
                alert(text);
              },
               error: function(xhr, status, error)
              {
                alert("Function failed!");
              }
        }); 
        return false; 
    });

});
```

My **problem** is that the `AJAX` call is working correctly, the object status is being updated, but the image and text does not change in a single click if I remove the `alert` call. If the `alert` call is there then the image and text change there itself.

However If I remove it then, the change takes place when I click it twice. Can anybody please tell me why am I experiencing this strange behaviour.

**Update:** I know this will sound weird, but it is the case. My script is sometimes working and sometimes now. And by not working I mean that `AJAX` call is always successful but sometimes the script responsible for changing the text and the image does not work.
This is really baffling.

Answer (score 1):

Have your `return false` inside Success and Error blocks.

Having it out will make that execute first and that may be the reason. `alert()` stops the execution of the script and that is why you see the expected if you have alert()

```
$(function() {

    $("a#update").click(function(){

        var curr_elem = $(this) ;
        var link = $(this).attr("href");

        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: link,
              success: function() 
              { 
                var text = curr_elem.parent().parent().find('span#sent_text').text();
                if (text == 'Completed')
                {
                    curr_elem.parent().parent().find('span#sent_text').html('In complete');
                    curr_elem.parent().parent().find('IMG').attr("src", "/static/images/check.jpeg");
                }
                else
                {
                    curr_elem.parent().parent().find('span#sent_text').html('Completed');
                    curr_elem.parent().parent().find('IMG').attr("src", "/static/images/unchecked.jpeg");
                }
               return false; 
              },
               error: function(xhr, status, error)
              {
                alert("Function failed!");
                return false; 
              }
        }); 

    });

});
```

Comment: Now there seems to be some new problem.. My js has stopped working altogether and the normal post request is being executed. In the `console.log` I can see this error `missing } after property list
GP_z(a="cb=f32a292a501ea3a&orig...&ackData[id]=1&width=90")/_/app...QQ/d=1/ (line 116)
Ye(a=message )`

Comment: So you are trying to make the same request twice? Once with a POST and next using AJAX ? Is this your requirement or you just want do a AJAX request? Why do you want to return false inside the AJAX callback ?

Comment: No I am not making a POST request and AJAX request together. Actually I have written the normal POST request as a fall back so in case there is some problem in javascript or it has been disabled, then the normal request will go through.

Comment: Probably that is not the way to go. What if JS works fine and if it is not disabled ? Did you try the fiddle ?

Comment: Since I am using Django, in the view I have written 
`if request_is_ajax():` so only of the calls is executed. Yes I treid the fiddle but somehow it is not working in my case